# How to jump to a specific file and line from an error output in Neovim?

Tags: neovim, python

I use Neovim as an IDE for Python development. When I execute a Python script inside Neovim using the `:terminal` command, and an error occurs, I get an output similar to the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/my_script.py", line 25, in <module>
    result = calculate_something(x, y)
  File "/path/to/my_script.py", line 15, in calculate_something
    return x / y
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

or `pytest` shows such a error output:

```
my_app/my_module.py:123: in process_data
    data = self.read_file(file_path)
my_app/file_utils.py:456: in read_file
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'missing_file.txt'
```

This output shows the file path, line number, and the error that occurred. I would like to be able to select one of these lines from the error output (e.g., File "/path/to/my_script.py", line 25, in ) and jump to the corresponding file and line in a new window within Neovim.

There are probably more error traceback stylings. So I dont want to write it my own and would hope that other face similiar demands and a good solution is already available.

Is there a built-in feature or a plugin that can help me achieve this? If so, how can I configure it to work with the error output format shown above?

Or is there an alternative workflow instead of using the `:terminal` command to get a similiar result.

Comment: You are probably interested in the help pages for gf, gF, make, the quickfix list.